# Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. running with emulator

Tags: gradle, android-emulator, build.gradle

I am new to android studio.Created basic flutter project and run the project works fine for Edge(web) emulator but when i changed to other emulators throwing errors and not able to proceed.

A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not load module metadata from C:\Users\admin.gradle\caches\modules-2\metadata-2.96\descriptors\javax.xml.bind\jaxb-api\2.3.1\a8be1fe3b3911d3d3425fe720cf42835\descriptor.bin

- Try:
  Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can tou share your build.gradle file ?

Comment: def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

Error near properties and GradleException

Answer (score 0):

Delete file .gradle from C:\Users<username>.gradle path resolved my problem.